# How to get public tweets (timeline) without making the user to login?

Tags: android, twitter

In the twitter API 1.1 , it says everything needs authentication.
API 1 allowed me to get the public tweets with a http Get without having authentication.

SO does this authentication means the end user need to authenticate? OR just an authentication from developer side or so?

Can anybody clarify this?

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two different kinds of authentication, it's all explained in the Twitter website:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/oauth#v1-1

If you use the application-only one the user won't have to log in. Different limits apply, in this case, the request limit is 180 per user with the application-user authentication or 300 per app with the application-only authentication.

Comment: so in my case, (to get public tweets only, no retweets/user context ) https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth  is enough right?

Comment: Yes. As you can see the API only says that it needs authentication. In other methods which need user-authentication the "resource information" tab includes that info (like this one: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/mentions_timeline) — So with the application-only authentication you're good to go.